# Custom (port-based or protocol ) routing with 2 isp

Tags: linux, networking, routing

My linux computer in the office:

```
> uname -a 
Linux 3.2.0-2-686-pae #1 SMP Tue Mar 20 19:48:26 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux.
```

It has 2 ISP, first one is static ip and default route:

```
> ip ro
default via 19.11.20.15 dev vlan40
19.11.20.0/27 dev vlan40  proto kernel  scope link  src 19.11.20.20
```

second one is gprs modem. I call wvdial without default route:

```
> ip ro
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.68.173.91
```

Second my computer at home on another network have public ip, but not always on.
His configuration very same, debian linux.

And my task is access to first computer by ssh, even if first isp fails.

Today I have using commands like:

```
ip ro add 46.48.10.56 via 10.64.64.64
while true ; do  ssh -R2221:127.0.0.1:22 server@46.48.10.56; done
```

And after that, I can connect to office by `ssh -p 2221 127.0.0.1` through second isp with modem.

Its good, but slow and expensive, because I use not only ssh but vnc, http etc beetween this two computers.

Thats why I want to use ISP1 for anything except ssh, and ISP2 for ssh.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [firewall marking](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.netfilter.html) along with [policy routing](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html). First create a new routing table which routes via ISP2:

```
echo 12 isp2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 10.64.64.64 table isp2
```

(That first command only needs to be run once ever.) Then add a routing policy rule to use this new table for packets with a certain firewall mark:

```
ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup isp2
```

And finally, use iptables to mark the packets you want to route specially:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but I've needed to source NAT packets routed by port:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Ah, doesnt work. Problem is: computer send 19.11.20.20 (src ip from isp1) to isp2, and packets discarded. I tryed to change ip route add default dev ppp0 src, but its doesnt help

Comment: https://gist.github.com/5062374 here is output

Comment: @KorjavinIvan See my edit.

Comment: Yeah, itss help. But I am still hope that its not best way. Nat? We have ip-s from isp2 network. Looks mad. But thanke you very much, its silve my problem.